# Elaboração de texto para descrição de paginação

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um texto no qual é mostrado a quantidade de itens que estão sendo visualizados por página baseado no total de itens no banco. Vejam uma imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Criei um "algoritmo" (que não estou achando legal) para definir em uma *label* este texto mostrando esses dados.

A função recebe:

- `currentPage`: Página atual considerando que 0 é a primeira página.
- `limitItensPerPage`: Quantidade limite por página, que o banco retorna por vez.
- `totalItens`: Quantidade total de itens que o banco de dados possui.

Gostaria de melhorar este "algoritmo" que fiz bem correndo. Vejam abaixo a função:

```js
generatePageText(1, 10, 55);

function generatePageText(currentPage, limitItensPerPage, totalItens) {
  var rows, lastItem;
  var firstItem = (currentPage + 1);
  
  // Esta condição foi criada porque o limitItensPerPage 
  // é atribuido através de um select option, e em alguns casos
  // pode haver um valor maior do que a quantidade de itens 
  if (limitItensPerPage > totalItens) {
    rows = totalItens;
    lastItem = totalItens;
  } else {
    rows = limitItensPerPage;
    lastItem = ((limitItensPerPage * firstItem) > totalItens) ? totalItens :
      limitItensPerPage * firstItem;
  }
  $('#show-qnd-itens-info').text("Mostrando itens do " +
    ((firstItem * rows) - rows + 1) + " ao " + lastItem + " de " + totalItens + ".");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="show-qnd-itens-info"></div>
```

Sabendo que é possível elaborar isso de várias formas, como eu poderia melhorar esta função?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lógica de escolher o conteúdo não está na pergunta. Parto do pressuposto que essa lógica tem um limitador para não carregar dados errados do select (caso o select como dizes escolha numeros grandes demais).

Partindo do pressuposto que isso é tratado nessa função, o mostrador poderia ser assim:

```js
generatePageText(1, 10, 55);

function generatePageText(currentPage, limitItensPerPage, totalItens) {
  const inicio = Math.min(currentPage * limitItensPerPage +1, totalItens);
  const fim = Math.min((currentPage + 1) * limitItensPerPage, totalItens);

  $('#show-qnd-itens-info').text("Mostrando itens do " +
    inicio + " ao " + fim + " de " + totalItens + ".");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="show-qnd-itens-info"></div>
```

No máximo mostra *"Mostrando itens do 55 ao 55 de 55."* e baseia-se no `Math.min` que retorna o valor menor de todos os argumentos que receber.

Por exemplo:

```
Math.min(4, 5, 7, 2, 8); // dá 2 pois é o menor de todos
```

Comment: Boa Sergio! Ótima solução! =D